# How can i move the player randomly between the waypoints?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What i'm trying to do is once the random flag is true move the player between the waypoints randomly.
but just calling the random method is not enough.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    public Transform target;
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float slowDownSpeed = 3f;
    public float reverseSlowDownSpeed = 3f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1f;
    private int targetsIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 originalPosition;
    private GameObject[] players;

    public Transform reverseTarget;
    private int reverseTargetsIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 reverseOriginalPosition;

    public bool random = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");
        players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        originalPosition = players[0].transform.localPosition;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (random == true)
        {
            RandomWayPointsAI();
        }
        else
        {
            WayPointsAI();
        } 
    }

    private void WayPointsAI()
    {
        if (targetsIndex == waypoints.Length)
            targetsIndex = 0;
        target = waypoints[targetsIndex].transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(players[0].transform.position, target.transform.position);
        players[0].transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(players[0].transform.localRotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - players[0].transform.localPosition), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        if (distance < 30)
        {
            players[0].transform.localPosition += players[0].transform.forward * slowDownSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            players[0].transform.localPosition += players[0].transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (distance < target.transform.localScale.magnitude)
        {
            targetsIndex++;
        }
    }

    private void ReverseWayPointsAI()
    {
        if (reverseTargetsIndex == 0)
            reverseTargetsIndex = waypoints.Length - 1;
        reverseTarget = waypoints[reverseTargetsIndex].transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(players[1].transform.position, reverseTarget.transform.position);
        players[1].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(players[1].transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(reverseTarget.position - players[1].transform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        if (distance < 30)
        {
            players[1].transform.position += players[1].transform.forward * reverseSlowDownSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            players[1].transform.position += players[1].transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (distance < reverseTarget.transform.localScale.magnitude)
        {
            reverseTargetsIndex--;
        }
    }

    void RandomWayPointsAI()
    {
        if (random == true)
        {
            int index = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
            target = waypoints[index].transform;
        }
    }

    void DrawLinesInScene()
    {
        // draw lines between each checkpoint //
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(waypoints[i].transform.position, waypoints[i + 1].transform.position, Color.blue);
        }

        // draw a line between the original transform start position 
        // and the current transform position //
        Debug.DrawLine(originalPosition, players[0].transform.position, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawLine(reverseOriginalPosition, players[1].transform.position, Color.red);

        // draw a line between current transform position and the next waypoint target
        // each time reached a waypoint.
        if (target != null)
            Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, players[0].transform.position, Color.green);
        if (reverseTarget != null)
            Debug.DrawLine(reverseTarget.transform.position, players[1].transform.position, Color.green);
    }

    void AddColliderToWaypoints()
    {
        foreach (GameObject go in waypoints)
        {
            SphereCollider sc = go.AddComponent<SphereCollider>() as SphereCollider;
            sc.isTrigger = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the Update i'm checking if random is true then calling the RandomWayPointsAI(); but it's not moving the player it's just keep picking up each frame a new random waypoint but that's it.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (random == true)
        {
            RandomWayPointsAI();
        }
        else
        {
            WayPointsAI();
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer. First you are not writing the movement code in the random function and you are expecting it to move.

```
bool getNextRandom = true;
void RandomWayPointsAI()
{
    if (random == true && getNextRandom)
    {
        int index = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
        target = waypoints[index].transform;
        getNextRandom = false;
    }
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(players[0].transform.position, target.transform.position);
    players[0].transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(players[0].transform.localRotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - players[0].transform.localPosition), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    //move towards the player
    if (distance < 30)
    {
        players[0].transform.localPosition += players[0].transform.forward * slowDownSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        players[0].transform.localPosition += players[0].transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (distance < target.transform.localScale.magnitude)
    {
        getNextRandom = true;
    }
}
```

Further you can imporve the solution by moving the movement code to another function which will give you better control

```
public GameObject[] waypoints;
public Transform target;
public float moveSpeed = 10f;
public float slowDownSpeed = 3f;
public float reverseSlowDownSpeed = 3f;
public float rotationSpeed = 1f;
private int targetsIndex = 0;
private Vector3 originalPosition;
private GameObject[] players;
public Transform reverseTarget;
private int reverseTargetsIndex = 0;
private Vector3 reverseOriginalPosition;
public bool random = false;
public bool getNextRandom = true;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");
    players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
    originalPosition = players[0].transform.localPosition;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (random == true)
    {
        RandomWayPointsAI();
    }
    else
    {
        WayPointsAI();
    }
}

private void WayPointsAI()
{
    if (targetsIndex == waypoints.Length)
        targetsIndex = 0;
    target = waypoints[targetsIndex].transform;

    if (MovePlayer())
        targetsIndex++;
}

private void ReverseWayPointsAI()
{
    if (reverseTargetsIndex == 0)
        reverseTargetsIndex = waypoints.Length - 1;
    reverseTarget = waypoints[reverseTargetsIndex].transform;

    if (MovePlayer())
        reverseTargetsIndex--;
}


void RandomWayPointsAI()
{
    if (random == true && getNextRandom)
    {
        int index = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
        target = waypoints[index].transform;
        getNextRandom = false;
    }
    getNextRandom = MovePlayer();
}

bool MovePlayer()
{
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(players[0].transform.position, target.transform.position);
    players[0].transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(players[0].transform.localRotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - players[0].transform.localPosition), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    //move towards the player
    if (distance < 30)
    {
        players[0].transform.localPosition += players[0].transform.forward * slowDownSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        players[0].transform.localPosition += players[0].transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (distance < target.transform.localScale.magnitude)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

void DrawLinesInScene()
{
    // draw lines between each checkpoint //
    for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(waypoints[i].transform.position, waypoints[i + 1].transform.position, Color.blue);
    }

    // draw a line between the original transform start position 
    // and the current transform position //
    Debug.DrawLine(originalPosition, players[0].transform.position, Color.red);
    Debug.DrawLine(reverseOriginalPosition, players[1].transform.position, Color.red);

    // draw a line between current transform position and the next waypoint target
    // each time reached a waypoint.
    if (target != null)
        Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, players[0].transform.position, Color.green);
    if (reverseTarget != null)
        Debug.DrawLine(reverseTarget.transform.position, players[1].transform.position, Color.green);
}

void AddColliderToWaypoints()
{
    foreach (GameObject go in waypoints)
    {
        SphereCollider sc = go.AddComponent<SphereCollider>() as SphereCollider;
        sc.isTrigger = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your RandomWayPointsAI() function, it only defines the index and the target but don't have any code below it to move the player.

```
private void WayPointsAI()
{
    if (targetsIndex == waypoints.Length)
        targetsIndex = 0;
    target = waypoints[targetsIndex].transform;
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(players[0].transform.position, target.transform.position);
    players[0].transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(players[0].transform.localRotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - players[0].transform.localPosition), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);


void RandomWayPointsAI()
{
    //No need to check if random is true anymore, you already checked when you run this function
    int index = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
    target = waypoints[index].transform;
    //float distance = Vector3.Distance(players[0].transform.position, target.transform.position);
    //players[0].transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(players[0].transform.localRotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - players[0].transform.localPosition), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);**
}
```